# What's the proper way to ask if you're expected to go to a meeting?

Tags: expressions, idiomatic-language

I received an e-mail in which I was CC'd by my boss. In it is a timetable of meetings and shoots. I'm the junior of a 4-man team so I don't really expect to be part of these meetings but since I received the e-mail, I want to make sure.

What is the proper way to ask if I'm invited to be part of the meeting/s?

- Hi boss, regarding the timetable, am I expected to go to all the meetings? Or go to X meeting on (date)?
- Hi boss, I read your e-mail and saw the timetable of the meetings next week. Am I invited to go?

I will be asking him via text message so I'm thinking of a casual but a respectable way to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hi boss** is very casual indeed although this has to do with etiquette rather than grammar. An alternative would be to use his/her first name. Your choice really depends on your relationship with your boss as well as the medium you are using to communicate.

One way of wording your inquiry might be: **Thank you for the timetable. Would you like me to attend all the meetings?**

That leaves your boss with the options of saying that the timetable was just for your information and that you need not attend; or specifying which meetings you should attend.

Comment: I agree it has to do with etiquette more than grammar. But I am not very eloquent when it comes to wording my inquiry, especially with these kinds of conversations where they're part of "small talk" or just plain quick inquiries.

Thanks for the answer. I liked how you worded it. It sounds natural and for some reason it's not as demanding as what I originally wrote.

Answer (score 0):

... regarding your email with the timetable - am I supposed to attend those meetings?